# UIDetailView does not load data when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called

Tags: ios, uitableview, detailview

In my TableViewController, I set the data I want to load in my DetailView (ws)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath sender:(id)sender{

    detailViewController *detailVC = [[detailViewController alloc] init];
    detailVC.ws = [self.tabAssociation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [detailVC viewDidLoad] ;


    //detailVC.descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

And this is what my DetailView must load

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.barre.title = self.ws.associationName ;
    self.descriptionTextView.text = self.ws.associationDescription ;
}
```

But when I select the row, a white page appears and not my associationDescription in a text view, neither my associationName
But my viewDidLoad seems to be called before detailVC.ws is loaded, ie my detailVC is empty

Here is my TableViewController.h

```
import UIKit/UIKit.h

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController{
    NSArray *tabAssociation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tabAssociation;


@end
```

And the TableViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {

}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController


@synthesize tabAssociation ;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *dictFromFile = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"AssociationTest" ofType:@"plist"]];    

    NSMutableArray *associationToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictFromFile objectEnumerator];
    NSDictionary *anObject;
    while ((anObject = [enumerator nextObject])) {
    association *newAssocition = [[association alloc] initWithDictionaryFromPlist: anObject];
        [associationToAdd addObject: newAssocition];

    }

    self.tabAssociation = [NSArray arrayWithArray:associationToAdd];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tabAssociation.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // On récupère l'objet Website qui correspon à la ligne que l'on souhaite afficher
    association *ws = [self.tabAssociation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = ws.associationName;

  // On renvoie la cellule configurée pour l'affichage
    return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath sender:(id)sender{

detailViewController *detailVC = [[detailViewController alloc] init];
detailVC.ws = [self.tabAssociation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//[detailVC viewDidLoad] ;
[self presentViewController:detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];


//detailVC.descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

//[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}

/*- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}*/

@end
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to call viewDidLoad manually. Try to set a breakpoint to see if the viewDidLoad is really called before you set the ws property.

Comment: Thank you @verbumdei , ,when I set a breakpoint at the end of my viewDidLoad , my self.ws is empty (0x000000). It means that my `detailVC.ws = [self.tabAssociation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is not called before the viewDidLoad ?

Comment: If you put two breakpoints, one in the viewDidLoad, and one just after the assignment of detailVC.ws, which one is called first? If viewDidLoad is called first, there might be something in your init method for detailViewController that triggers it?

Comment: when I set a breakpoint in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the simulator shows me an empty View when I select a row on my talbeView, but it is not stopped by the breakpoint. That means my didSelectRowAtIndexPath is never called?

Comment: Moreover, when I set 2 breakpoints, my viewdidLoad is called fist as you said

Comment: Have you set your table view delegate?

Comment: I dont think, I have an AppDelegate.h and .m but I have wrote nothing on it

Comment: So is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath called at all? I think you need to paste your whole implementation of the TableViewController. Also check if it is a subclass of UITableViewController or you add the UITableView manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call -viewDidLoad directly. What you want to do is present you `detailViewController` somehow.

If you're inside a `UINavigationController`, something like:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
```

should work. If you're not, then you have to think about how you're going to present your view controller.

You can try something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath sender:(id)sender{

    detailViewController *detailVC = [[detailViewController alloc] init];
    detailVC.ws = [self.tabAssociation objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self presentViewController: detailVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```